# FBConnect Demo Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fbconnect

I am running the demo application that is supplied with the facebook-ios-sdk. The application starts in the emulator, with a LogIn button. I click the button which then launches safari to grant access to the application. I log in with my fb creds and allow the application. I am the administrator for the application and I have verified I put in the right app key.

After I allow access, it says "Safari cannot open the page because the address in invalid"...this is the url it's trying to go to: http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php...

So am I missing something because the breakpoint for `(void)fbDidLogin` never gets hit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem... I didnt bind my application to a URL scheme corresponding to my Facebook application ID. Once I did this the callbacks were working properly.

Comment: Note that the answer to this question has the code for the binding you mention, which is helpful to folks just starting.  Include it here for an upvote.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131178/facebook-ios-safari-cannot-open-page-error-when-authenticating-user-with-singl

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of your registration. I think you put the wrong thing in the website field

Answer (score 0):

its detailed in the Facebook SDK README file -

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/README.mdown

scroll down to the Authentication and Authorization section, it walks you though it.

Don't want to post it here, incase it ever changes

-Jonathan