# Facebook iOS Safari "Cannot Open Page Error" When Authenticating User with Single-Sign-On

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, oauth

I'm spinning in circles with this issue - and it looks like Facebook has some open tickets regarding it, but I wanted to see if anyone had the same issue I'm having and found a temporary or better solution.

I downloaded Facebook's "DemoApp", and can put in my `appId` into its info.plist as so: `fb1234567890` (where 1234567890 is my appId).  It can authenticate the user by multitasking to Safari, entering my credentials, allowing my application access, and then redirecting back to "DemoApp" with me logged in (and I can request my information fine).

**NOW, I'm trying to integrate DemoApp's functionality into my existing application.**

I am able to access the login screen, and enter my credentials.  It allows me to give my application access to my personal information - I click `allow` and Safari processes a new request, and then returns the **error message**: `Safari cannot open the request because the address is invalid` at the URL: `http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php`

HOWEVER, If I have `DemoApp` installed on my simulator and my own application, it will switch BACK to DemoApp with my successfully logged in.  If I uninstall `DemoApp` and try again with my application, I get the Safari error.

**WHAT CAN I DO TO SOLVE THIS??**  Any help would be great; I'm banging my head here.:(

My `info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb1234567890</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't have your Info.plist set up correctly. Can you post it?

Comment: Hey again Anomie:) I've added my info.plist.

Comment: You might want to obscure your facebook app id...

Comment: Good point.  I am just uing this one for development, and plan on receiving a new one later, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SimonGoldeen: why? the ID is public, only the secret is secret, as the name implies...

Answer (score 38):

The CFBundleURLTypes entry is incorrect.  It should look like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb1234567890</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: For everyone following the tutorial on the Facebook developer site: Pay attention to _this_ line: `<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>`! It is easy to misunderstand this in the tutorial and written __correctly__ here! Thanks Mark

Comment: Just a clarification that I wouldve appreciated over the last couple hours, but for those doing this within xcode: The key name appears "URL types" (note lower case t) and within that the key name appears "URL Schemes" (note the upper case S". No idea why but this seems to be the way to make it work!

Comment: @aking63: the difference you're seeing is that you're using the plist-editor with NOT raw-key/value names shown.  Right-click on "URLtypes" and select SHOW RAW KEYS/VALUES and you'll see the CFBundle... names.  (You can toggle back, if you like.)

Comment: some common things that can be missed: make sure that within the `CFBundleURLSchemes` with "fb". Also the number you put there is your app id, not your app secret.

Comment: I check all my facebook setting as given and still got the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar experience.  I found that the plist changes I was making were simply not being absorbed into the simulator, even after a clean build.  I was able to make them take by changing the Hardware->Device setting to something different, and then back again.  Somehow, this appears to have caused the plist changes to register with the OS on the simulator, whereas nothing else I did had that effect.  Not sure this is the "right" way to do it, or if something in the build settings is messed up, but this, for me, did work around the exact problem you are describing.

Answer (score 3):

Marks answer steered me in the right direction but my problem was a bit different. For some reason the plist looked like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb1234567890
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@&quot;FBExpirationDat</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I just deleted the data after the id and it was fixed:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb1234567890</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```