# iOS 6 Facebook sdk not call my app back

Tags: facebook, ios6

I'm new to iOS and trying to integrate FB in my iOS application. I'm following instructions from [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/).

Now the problem is that when I click the login button my app is not called back after login; instead it shows a dialog box saying:

> Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with the same issue for quite a while until I found out I had mistyped a key in the application plist (it's "URL Schemes" not "URL schemes"), see the top answer and comments here: [Facebook iOS Safari "Cannot Open Page Error" When Authenticating User with Single-Sign-On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131178/facebook-ios-safari-cannot-open-page-error-when-authenticating-user-with-singl).