# iOS6 Facebook Safari “Cannot Open Page Error”

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I am integrating Facebook into my iOS app and have been folowing the tutorial on Facebook's website. After finishing with the login code I built and run the app. I have no errors but when login is tapped it redirects me to Facebook safari for auth. When this happens Facebook just says an error has occured and to try again later. I have done some reserch and have looked at the question below where I checked my plist as well as I have checked to make sure my app id is correct. I am lost as to what is going wrong below is also a copy of my plist. Thank you.

[Facebook iOS Safari "Cannot Open Page Error" When Authenticating User with Single-Sign-On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131178/facebook-ios-safari-cannot-open-page-error-when-authenticating-user-with-singl)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with SSO in old apps with SDK version 2.0 it was down to having it selected and having the correct bundle ID added in App on Facebook Developer

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.5 sdk. Also can u clarify what u mean by "selected" and putting the bundle id into Facebook. Thank you.

Comment: If you go to developer.facebook.com and select your app - you need to enter the Native iOS information